# Create Sybase function with exception handling

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I want to create function to use it in creation of view.
In my table there are strings (strings are consists only of 8 digits) that I'm converting into DATE.

My function is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MY.FUNCTION(@date int)
  RETURNS DATE 
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN CONVERT(DATETIME, @date)
END
```

If I use smth like `SELECT FUNCTION('20170323') FROM TABLE` it works as expected.
But if I'll try smth like `SELECT FUNCTION('77777777') FROM TABLE` it fails of course... But if it fail I need to retut NULL!
After some digging I have no result about function modification.
How to add exception handling in my function properly to return date on NULL if it fails?

Comment: DB is: ASE 15.7

Comment: oh, did not notice the RDBMS, mine is for sql server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long investigation and lot of efforts I've found my solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION(@date CHAR(20))
  RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
RETURN
(CASE
  WHEN ISDATE(@date) = 0
  THEN NULL
  ELSE CAST(@date AS DATE)
END)
END
```

Sybase method ISDATE() doing all magic in this case without throwing exception...

Answer (score 0):

use `TRY_CONVERT` instead of `CONVERT`, which would be :

```
CREATE FUNCTION TEST(@date varchar(50))
  RETURNS DATETIME 
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, @date)
END
```

Result:

```
select [dbo].[TEST]('20171201')  --output:2017-12-01 00:00:00.000
select [dbo].[TEST]('9999999999') --output: NULL
```

Comment: I recommend use the 1st method, which is the existing build in function to return `NULL` if conversion failed

Comment: 1 method: "Invalid column name 'DATETIME"
2 method: tried before asking the question... "Incorrect syntax near 'TRY'"

Comment: 1 - "Illegal SELECT statement within a scalar SQL function"

Comment: Again gives "Invalid column name 'DATETIME"

Comment: do not use `int` as the input data type, use `varchar`

Comment: sure, it just typo.
I'm using proper type.

Comment: @Alex13ss, and the output data type better matches the `convert` data type

Comment: Not working... Tried all options. Can the problem be in DB version?

Comment: cannot be, which RDBMS are you using? SQL server?

Comment: I'm using Sybase Central